# Count frequency of 8-bit symbols from file

Tags: c, compression

I have next challenge and need a little help ;)

> Program to write: The file is treated as a row of 8-bit symbols.
>
> 1. Count the frequency (incidence) of these symbols
> 2. Count the frequency of these symbols after symbols (if the previous character is given, in front of first charakter is sign with code 0).
>
> The program should work for doc, pdf, mp4, jpg (take a min 1MB file).

So I wrote a little bit of code; here it is:

main:

```
int array[256] = {0};
double charArray[256][256] = {{0}};

FILE *fp = fopen("test.txt", "rb");

int c;
int b = 0;

printf("File content: \n");
while((c = fgetc(fp)) != EOF)
{
    printf("%2x", c);
    ++charArray[b][c];
    ++array[c];
    b=c;
}

int k;

printf("\nSymbols frequency counter: \n");
for(k=0;k<256;k++) {
    if(array[k] > 0 ) {
        printf("char %2x: %d times \n", k, array[k]);
    }
}


int y,z;
printf("Symbols after symbols frequency counter: \n");

for(y=0;y<256;y++){

    for(z=0;z<256;z++){

        if(charArray[y][z] > 0) {
        printf("char %2x after char %2x: %.0f times\n", z, y, charArray[y][z]);
        }
    }
}

fclose(fp);

return 0;
```

EDIT: It's now good?

Comment: Yes, this looks reasonable to me. `fgetc` takes care of any signed char pitfalls for you. As for your second question you can keep track of the last read character and use it as the second index ("context") into a [256][256] frequency table, much as you do already. Beware of the first character though.

Comment: the will be unprintable characters in almost any file.  some characters, when printed with '%c' will have adverse effects upon the display.  strongly suggest printing the symbols via '%2x'

Comment: Your loop condition is funky though, stopping on '\0'. You want `while((c = fgetc(fp)) != EOF)` instead.

Comment: @doynax ok, i fixed this loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Now i need a help, what will be the best way to write a 2* point?

Nearly the same as you're currently doing, except you need to use a 2D array and keep track of the previous character you saw, e.g.

```
++charArray[b][c];
b = c;
```

And, of course, you'll need to handle both dimensions when printing the array.

Comment: @doynax wrote about this solution too, but unfortunately i dont know how i should write this. 
I can initialize table, but dont know how it should work in a loop.

Comment: The code included in my answer is everything you'd need in the loop. Declare the variable `b` outside the loop, so that it keeps its value across iterations, and initialize it to zero.